# Is there a way to make large HTML snippets in my post more manageable?

Tags: wordpress

In a post, I have an html table that is hundreds of lines long!

In "text" view this is very unwieldy (but OK in "visual" view for the post).

Can I move all of the code somewhere else and replace it in the post with a [shortcode] or something?

Comment: Yes you could use a shortcode for it.

Comment: You can create custom post type, or a custom shortcode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using a Custom Post Type for your code is a good idea. You can then register a shortcode to embed the code in a different post. This offers a bunch of benefits, you can maintain one snippet of code, and display that snippet in multiple places. If you want to code your own solution there are plenty of resources for doing so:

[Registering Custom Post Types](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/registering-custom-post-types/)

[Creating Shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Of course there are already plugins that do this for you. I really like this one:

[Code Snippets CPT](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets-cpt/)

It registers a CPT called "Code Snippets". You just create a new Code Snippet, put your code in the content of that Code Snippet. And  has styling options and syntax highlighting for tons of different kind of code (including HTML). Above the post editor it will give you a shortcode like the one below that you can use to embed the code anywhere else on your site:

```
[snippet slug=my-example-html-snippet lang=html]
```

Here's an [example of a post](https://jumpoff.io/multiple-shift-registers-test/) that has multiple snippets embedded in it.